Question regarding the completeness and incompleteness theorems and the provability predicate
So recently I've been thinking about the incompleteness theorems, specifically the first one. One often sees a proof of the first incompleteness theorem using the diagonal lemma and a "provability predicate". So what I mean is let's say $T$ is some formal system of arithmetic (like $PA$, $Q$ or any other that is strong enough for the incompleteness theorem), then one can define the formula $Prf(\varphi)$ which in broad terms means "There exists a proof of $\varphi$ in $T$", and then using the diagonal lemma it is shown that there exists a formula $G$
such that $T \vdash G \leftrightarrow \neg Prf(\ulcorner G \urcorner)$.
Now, let's call the formula $G \leftrightarrow \neg Prf(\ulcorner G \urcorner)$ as $\phi$
According to Gödel's completeness theorem sice $T \vdash \phi$ it follows that $\phi$ must be true in every model of $T$. Also according to Gödel's completeness theorem, since $T \nvdash G$ then $G$ must be true in some models of $T$ while false in others.
So let's say $\mathfrak{M}$ is a model of $T$. Then either:

Both $\phi$ and $G$ are true in $\mathfrak{M}$. But then by the structure of $\phi$ it is implied that $\neg Prf(\ulcorner G \urcorner)$ is also true, which means $G$ is not provable according to $\mathfrak{M}$ (This is already strange since provability should be independent of models).
$\phi$ is true while $G$ is false. Which then would imply that in $\mathfrak{M}$, $\neg Prf(\ulcorner G \urcorner)$ is false, that is, $G$ is provable in $\mathfrak{M}$ but this contradicts that $G$ is not provable at all (And again provability is independent of models).

So clearly I am misunderstanding something, but I just can't figure out what. I'm not a mathematician, nor a logician. I'm just simply interested in the incompleteness theorems, so any help would be appreciated!

Some comments: if $T \vdash \phi$ by Completeness of the logic the theorem $\phi$ is true in every model of theory $T$ (the intended one as well as the "weird" ones; see non.standard models of arithmetic).

If $G$ is the "gödel sentence" that, according to Godel Incompleteness Theorem, is undecidable wrt theory $T$, we have that $T \nvdash G$ and thus $T \nvDash G$, that menas that there is some (at least one) model of $T$ where formula $G$ is false. And the same for $\lnot G$. The two models of $T$ are not the same :-)

Provability is not independent of models. If a statement is provable, it is provable according to all models, but an unprovable statement can be provable according to certain models.

@spaceisdarkgreen Given that '=' is a binary relation, some structures have that relation of equality, some don't.  Equality has a bunch of inference rules associated with it.  Thus, if the structure doesn't have equality, it's inference rules differ from one that does, and thus what can get proved also differs.  So, different models even with the same first-order logic axioms can easily have different theorems.  Maybe as an example, if there are no inference rules with '=' in the wffs, since '=' does not exist in the model, how could we prove '(2+2) = 4'?

The predicate $Prf$ expresses something a bit different than what you think it does.
Let us say that $Prf(a)$ holds in  model $A$. That just means that there is $w\in A$ that "witnesses" that $a$ holds in $A$. If $A$ is a standard model of natural numbers, then the witness $w$ is always a natural number, so you can convert it to the proof of $a$ through Gödel's encoding.
But $A$ could also be a non-standard model, and thus $w$ could be a non-standard element/number (you can think of it as a number which is greater than all natural numbers) with no way how to convert it to the "on-paper-written" proof.

I'm writing this quickly on the tablet, let me know if I should elaborate more.

Your answer is very helpful, indeed I have heard that the Gödel sentence is true in the standard model, which seems to line up with your answer. So in this weird nonstandard model, $Prf(a)$ does hold, which means that despite the fact that we can show that $T \nvdash G$ and $T \nvdash \neg G$, this doesn't translate to $T \vdash \neg Prf(\ulcorner G \urcorner)$, which seems to be the main cause of my misunderstanding. Am I understanding this correctly?

I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you are asking here. If $T\not\vdash G$ and $T\not\vdash\neg G$, then this does not translate to $T\vdash \neg Prf(\overline{G})$, but you can claim that there is no proof of $G$ in $T$.

There is a difference between claiming that $G$ is not provable in $T$ from the position of some theory stronger than $T$ and claiming that $T$ "does know" that $G$ is not provable in it.

This might be a long comment and I may have to split it in two.  So I've done some reflecting, and I realized that my understanding of the provability predicate used in the incompleteness theorem is completely wrong. First of all it should have been obvious to me that just because we can show that $T \nvdash G$ and $T \nvdash \neg G$, we can't say that $T \vdash \neg Prf(\ulcorner G \urcorner)$, if we could then exactly by the fact that $T \vdash G \leftrightarrow \neg Prf(\ulcorner G \urcorner)$, we could show that $T \vdash G$, which is a contradicton.

And then I understood, that the provability predicate is ultimately just a statement about numbers. It is only when interpreting it in terms of the natural numbers does it have the meaning we want it to have, because all of our Gödel numbering was done using natural numbers! Therefore now it seems obvious that in a nonstandard model, weird numbers could slip in and say "I am the proof of $G$", but we would have no way of decoding that proof. This also seems like the reason why $G$ is true in the natural numbers. So thank you very much for your answer, it was very helpful to me.

Yes, I think you pretty much got it :)
